# preg_replace or str_replace don't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm French newbie, and I have a little question. I want to remove double quotes by \" with php. I have been trying this preg_replace but it doesn't work, and I have the same sentence in $test.

```
function debgScript($file, $var){
   $test = "Vous devez d'abord nous informer sur le nombre de personnes qui voyagent (Voir dans l'onglet "INFO VOYAGE")";
   $var = preg_replace("/\"/", "\"", $test);
   $monfichier = fopen($file, 'a');
   fputs($monfichier, $var);
   fclose($monfichier);
}
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Just being curious, why do you need to replace double quotes with \" ?

Comment: If you want to remove double quotes, don't replace them with a double quote: `$var = preg_replace("/\"/", "", $test);`

Comment: $var = preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", $test);try it

Comment: use `addslashes`. Also want to mention, your snippet can run correctly? your `$test` is not a correct php syntax at all. Your `"` broke the assignment.

Comment: We generate variables with the content of excel file, we need to add slashes only for the double quotes. Thank for respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$var = preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are having trouble removing double quotes from your `$test` variable is because there are no double quotes in that variable. You are using double quotes to define the variable

`$test = "...."INFO VOYAGE")";`

This is the wrong syntax. As soon as you reach the double quote in front of INFO VOYAGE, you leave the string. There are a coupe ways you can fix this.

- You can escape the double quotes in the assignment
- You can concatenate a double quote character
- probably many other creative ways also, the list goes on

Basically your choice will depend on how your input is coming in, but suffice to say that you cannot include a double quote inside a double quoted string without taking extra steps.